# UIWebView can't open Twitter tweets but Safari can

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, user-agent

This question is about how to change the User Agent in the UIWebView only for specific URLs (Twitter).

Example, when I try to open a tweet URL from Twitter, for example: http://www.twitter.com/ManUtd/status/374411877407031296

In the UIWebView I will get a Twitter Banner:

[image: In the UIWebView I will get a Twitter Banner:]

While the exact same URL in the Safari will open this page:

[image]

Obviously it's the User Agent that play its part in this behaviour.

What's the best practice to:

1) Change the User Agent in the WebView for Twitter links to the same one as Safari

2) For other links use the original User Agent of the UIWebView.

Comment: you can search for how to change user agent there were lots of links available in stackoverflow

Comment: Thanks, I saw those links but what I care about is the best practice to get back to the orignal User Agent if the link is not from Twitter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the user agent with this code:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Your user agent", @"UserAgent", nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionary];
```

Comment: I asked what's the best practice... I want to get back to the orignal USer Agent if the link is not from Twitter